# Business microdata from UK Data Service

Tags: releasing-data, economics, uk

[UK Data Service](http://ukdataservice.ac.uk/get-data/key-data/business-microdata) has several very interesting business surveys with the data that rarely appear elsewhere. It describes turnover, cost of capital, organizational structure, and other microeconomic variables.

But the problem is that the access is granted only to certain institutions (not sure if they pay for it). I also haven't found this data elsewhere.

Are there any ways to obtain this data, except through these institutions?

Answer (score 2):

If you do want to obtain microdata, the answer is no. The data is sensitive and the risk of disclosure is very high, i.e. individual businesses can easily be identified. That's why the Data Service is more strict and asks for further guarantees, such as the affiliation with an institution they trust.

You can also have [access to microdata via Eurostat](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/microdata). However, this access is only granted for scientific purposes and you have to be affiliated with an institution recognised by Eurostat. So, the situation is the same as above.

If you can do with "aggregated" data, you can have a look at the tables readily supplied by [ONS](http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/datasets-and-tables/index.html) and [Eurostat](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/data/database).

As a last resort, if the information you are looking for is not readily available, you can contact these two institutions directly and ask for tailor made extractions.